# How to loop an animation on jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops, animation, onload

I was just wondering how to loop my animation (1 horizontally moving rectangle).
Also how do I make the animation occur once the page has fully loaded, instead of having to instigate the animation by clicking a button, as my coding shows at the moment.
Sorry I'm new to jQuery and just getting used to the basics. Thanks for any help!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div2").animate({right:'1000px'}, 7000);
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="div2" style="background:#e1e1e0;opacity:0.4;height:100px;width:500px;position:absolute;"></div>
```

Comment: (Personal Opinion) You should carefully consider whether or not you really _need_ an animation when the page loads. Animations cause the entire page to reflow (recalculate positions) every time an element is moved/resized. It probably won't have an adverse effect on a page, but if this is part of JavaScript application, it will just be extra overhead.

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a function and then have the `animate()` method call the function in it's callback parameter:

```
function animateRect(){
    $("#div2").css({right:0}).animate({right:'1000px'}, 7000, animateRect);
}
```

I've aldo added a `css()` method in there to reset the element's right position, otherwise there will only ever be 1 animation.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7WKmP/1)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, all you need is to remove click handler, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#div2").animate({right:'1000px'}, 7000);
});
```

This way the animation will start itself without the need to click